# Extra html code added in html file while deploying from Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html

I'm using `angularjs` for developing with `sharepoint 2013`. I have created a directive in `angularjs` whose `html` file is not added specifically in a page. When I inject the module of this directive in a page, then this html should be rendered there. This is the expected scenario. Now, I'm getting into a strange situation where my `html` files are added with some extra `html` tags. I don't have any idea, why this is coming ? This is not coming for the html files which are explicitely called in a page which uses a master page.

A sample html tag which is added to my html tags, is given below.

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">PHXYVHQD4PQR-6-15870</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">b753ac5b-a154-42d1-a7db-90e4d1193a6d</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://esiadsspdplot2/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=PHXYVHQD4PQR-6-15870, PHXYVHQD4PQR-6-15870</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Any thoughts on this issue ?

Comment: Are you deploying the page to a document library?

Comment: No. Its in the catalogs\masterpage itself.

Comment: Any suggessions for resolving this issue ?